# Cypress exits the tests execution environment after all it blocks are finished

Tags: testing, cypress, reload

I have one big describe with nested describes and it blocks.
I wanted to have each it block within its describe. The issue is that cypress exists the tests runner after all tests are run. I want to preserve those it blocks tests in order to see the history entries.

```
describe("Move timetable until the specified event is executed", () => {
  describe("Login", () => {
    it("should log in and retrive the timetable related info", () => {
      cy.login()
    });
  });
  describe("Access dedicated menu leaf", () => {
    it("should access the Maintenance menu and click on Execute", () => {
      executeCurrentTimetable.accessMenuLeafAndClickExecute();
    });

    describe("Execute events until specified event is executed", () => {
      it("should execute the timetable until a specified event is reached", () => {
        // get the event based on eventsList array
        executeCurrentTimetable.executeEvents(eventKeyObj.SoBD);
  });
});
```

Only if all commands are wrapped within the same describe and it block works:

```
    describe("Execute events until last event of the day", () => {
      it.only("should execute the timetable until a specified event is reached", () => {
        cy.login()
        executeCurrentTimetable.accessMenuLeafAndClickExecute();
        executeCurrentTimetable.executeLastEvent();
      });
    });
```

After the tests are completed cypress automatically goes to the menu (see picture).
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--no-exit` flag to prevent an exit after execution. See `npx cypress run --help` for more information. Here is the [issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1871) of the feature.
Example: `npx cypress run --no-exit`